# Autocomplete in Angularjs with json value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning to do autocomplete using pure AngularJS and the below code which I have copied from YouTube video.

I am stuck on this particular part:

Controller

```
myApp.controller("myWeatherContrl", function ($scope, weatherService) {
$scope.title = "Weather App";
weatherService.getCities().then(function (response) {
    $scope.data = response;
    //console.log("Say Hi", $scope.data);
})

$scope.complete = function (string) {
    var output = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.data, function (city) {
        if (city.toLowerCase().indexOf(string.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
            output.push(city);
        }
    });
    $scope.filterCity = output;
};
$scope.fillTextbox = function(string){
    $scope.city = string;
    $scope.hidethis = true;
};
});
```

Service

```
myApp.service("weatherService", ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
return {
    getCities: function () {
        return $http.get('data/data.json');
        }
   };
}]);
```

HTML (Directive)

```
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" id="city" ng-keyup="complete(city)" placeholder="Enter City Name" class="form-control" ng-model="city"/>
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-model="hidethis" ng-hide="hidethis" ng-click="fillTextbox(citydata)" ng-repeat="citydata in filterCity">
        {{citydata}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Weather App</title>    
   <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
 <body ng-app="myWeatherApp" ng-controller="myWeatherContrl">
 <div class="container">  
    <label ng-cloak>{{title}}</label>
     <ui-view></ui-view>
 </div>    
 <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
 <script src="app.js"></script>    
 <script src="Scripts/controller/weathercntrl.js"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/service/weather.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I am getting an error as **city.toLowerCase is not a function**.

Comment: your code is incomplete. where are you calling getCities function?

Comment: I have updated my code

Comment: You need to make sure `$scope.data` is an array of strings, as [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) is a prototype of `String`. You are getting the error "city.toLowerCase is not a function" because at the point of executing the [`angular.forEach`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) method, the [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) `city` in your loop is not "string".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("myWeatherContrl", function($scope, weatherService) {
  $scope.title = "Weather App";
  
  $scope.obj = {};
  $scope.obj.data = [];
  weatherService.getCities().then(function(response) {
    angular.forEach(response.data, function(state) {

      angular.forEach(state, function(city) {

        if (typeof city === "string") {
          $scope.obj.data .push(city);
        }
      });
    });

    console.log("Say Hi", $scope.data);
  })

  $scope.complete = function(string) {
    var output = [];
    if (string.length >= 3) {
      angular.forEach($scope.obj.data , function(city) {
        if (city.toLowerCase().indexOf(string.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
          output.push(city);
        }
      });
    }
    $scope.filterCity = output;
  };
  $scope.fillTextbox = function(string) {
    $scope.city = string;
    $scope.hidethis = true;
  };
});
myApp.service("weatherService", ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
  return {
    getCities: function() {
      return $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/pufq5');
    }
  };
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myWeatherContrl">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" id="city" ng-keyup="complete(obj.city)" placeholder="Enter City Name" class="form-control" ng-model="obj.city" />
      <ul ng-if="obj.data.length>0" class="list-group">
        <li style="cursor:pointer" class="list-group-item" ng-click="obj.city = citydata;obj.data={};" ng-repeat="citydata in filterCity track by $index">
          {{citydata}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks @Gaurav the error is not coming but i am not getting the autocomplete in my view

Comment: it means your json is in different format. please share your json structure.

Comment: do you want to search for state for city?

Comment: only City not for state

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152564/discussion-between-mahadevan-and-gaurav-srivastava).

Comment: A <li> tag should not contain ng-model

Comment: @Vivz thanx bro. i didn't saw that. fixed it :-)

Answer (score 0):

When doing `weatherService.getCities().then(function (response)...`, the response must not be returning a list of strings.

This means that when you call `angular.forEach($scope.data, function (city) {` the `city` variable is not being populated with a string.

Add `console.log(city)` in your `forEach` loop to assist debugging.

Comment: I think if you add snippets instead of just code tags, it'll have better readability, even if the snippets are just a couple of lines each.